# ElasticSearch Date Range Query not working for custom date format

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created a test index in elasticsearch with mapping for 2 date fields. Both fields have custom format as shown below.

```
{
  "test" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "_doc" : {
        "properties" : {
          "endTime" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
          },
          "startTime" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data i have loaded for this sample test index looks like below.

```
PUT test/_doc
{
  "startTime" : "2019-02-26 00:00:00.000",
  "endTime" : "2019-02-27 00:00:00.000"
}
```

I am trying to query based on range but it doesnt return any result. Am i missing something? My query for range is as below.

```
GET test/_doc/search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "range": {
          "endTime": {
            "gte": "2019-02-25 00:00:00.000",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got everything right... except the search endpoint, which is `_search` not `search`

```
GET test/_doc/_search
              ^
              |
           add this
```

Also note that you probably have created a new document whose id is `search`, you probably want to delete it using `DELETE test/_doc/search`.

Comment: Yes seems like that was the mistake. Thanks

Comment: Also note that for the benefit of others, you should ask a new question instead of modifying the original one to ask a new unrelated question...